# Prevent MS Word mail merge from MS Access query from locking the file

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, locking

I have an MS Word document for a mail merge, and I want it to use a particular MS Access form to pull the data from a query. However this locks the file, which is a problem because it's also the file I use. Thus I have to close my file before opening the mail merge.

How do I set the MS Access file to not be locked by anything?

Comment: [Use mail merge to send Access data to Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-to-send-access-data-to-word-053cc639-fe30-4d3a-943d-0bee0892f16a)

Comment: Are you certain it's being opened in shared mode within Access?  If Access is set to open it up in exclusive mode, even if Word is opening it in shared mode, Access won't be able to open in exclusive mode.  In other words, are you certain it is Word that is being the "greedy" application?  BTW, Access may elevate to exclusive mode if you edit tables, etc.

Comment: Here's a possible workaround, but I don't have time to test:  Create a separate Access "front end" database with linked tables pointing to the original database.  Create the mail merge using the new linked database.  I suspect that it will lock that database, but not the original backend database.  I suppose it could still place record-level locks, but hopefully doesn't require closing the entire file.   (I call it "frontend" because this follows the same pattern for UI front ends with linked tables even though really it is a middle-man database in this case.)

Comment: This is not a programming question and is thus off-topic on Stack Overflow.